# Understanding how `lw` and `sw` actually work in a MIPS program

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I'm having bit of a difficulty understanding what `sw` and `lw` do in a MIPS program. My understanding of the topic is that we use `lw` to transfer data from the memory into the register and vice-versa for `sw`. But how is this exactly accomplished?

Let's say we have the following line of code:

```
lw Reg.Dest, Offset(Reg.Source)
sw Reg.Source, Offset(Reg.Dest)
```

If we concentrate on `lw` it's essentially storing the data from the memory, `Reg.Source` and multiplying the address of that data with the `Offset`, always a multiple of $4$ because the registers deal with $32$ bits and the memory uses $8$ bits, into a specific address in the register which is equal to `Offset + Reg.Source` - so if we say that `Offset = 16, Reg.Source = $s1 = 12` then the register will store the data from the memory into the address $28$ in the register.

Assuming that my understanding of `lw` is correct, my question is then how does `sw` work?

PS: It would be great if the answers could also contain just a one liner example such as `sw $t0, 32($s3)`.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066664/4271923 (although your wording and question seems a bit more mixed up and using imprecise wording, which makes it difficult to say if you are also confused, or just don't use the "lingo")

Comment: Also one more extra note... the 32 bits of register are physically stored directly on the CPU chip, so it's super fast for CPU to use them in instructions (but you have only 32 registers available in MIPS CPU = 32*4 = 128 bytes, while computer memory chips are often in thousands/millions/billions of bytes sizes). To load/store anything from/to memory, it takes lot more, as memory is different chip and the CPU must undergo extra communication with the memory chip, telling it which address to select and wait for read, or send value for write to it (that's what `sw` does).

Comment: Doesn't the official documentation already explain this sufficiently? For example: `SW rt, offset(base)` **Description:** `memory[base+offset] ← rt`
The least-significant 32-bit word of register _rt_ is stored in memory at the location specified by the aligned effective
address. The 16-bit signed _offset_ is added to the contents of GPR _base_ to form the effective address.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

lw (load word) loads a word from memory to a register.

```
lw $2, 4($4) # $2 <- mem($4+4)
```

$2 is the destination register and $4 the address register. And the source of information is the memory.

4 is an offset that is added (not multiplied) to the address register. This kind of memory access is called based addressing and is it quite useful in many situations. For instance, if $4 hold the address of a struct, the offset allows to pick the different fields of the struct. Or the next or previous element in a array, etc. offset does not have to be a multiple of 4, but (address register + offset) must and most of the time both are.

Sw is similar, but stores a register into memory.

```
 sw $5, 8($7) # mem[$7+8] <- $5
```

Again $7 is the register holding the memory address, 8 an offset and $5 is the source of the information that will be written in memory.

Note that contrary to others MIPS instructions, the first operand is the source, not the destination. Probably this is to enforce the fact that the address register plays a similar role in both instruction, while in lw it is used to compute the memory address of the source of data and in sw the memory destination address.