# source and destination register for lw and sw instruction in MIPS

Tags: mips

I am finding a contradiction in various sources in the rs and rt registers used in MIPS for lw and sw instruction.
For example, [http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~zwang/files/cda3101/Fall2017/Lecture5_cda3101.pdf](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Ezwang/files/cda3101/Fall2017/Lecture5_cda3101.pdf)
[image]

But in the below stackoverflow question, the source and destination registers of sw and lw are kind of opposite: [Understanding how `lw` and `sw` actually work in a MIPS program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54136371/understanding-how-lw-and-sw-actually-work-in-a-mips-program). I found something similar at some other places also. Which one is correct?

Comment: Opposite how? In the case of an `lw` you're loading from memory into register `rt`, and in case of an `sw` you're storing register `rt` to memory. That seems to be what both your picture and the linked question say.

Comment: Thank you @Michael for the response. The notation of MIPS I have studied means, rs= first source register, rt= destination register, and rd= second source register.  In stackoverflow question, the format of lw and sw is as: lw Reg.Dest, Offset(Reg.Source)
sw Reg.Source, Offset(Reg.Dest)

Comment: I don't think you should focus too much on the names `rs` and `rt`, and rather read the description of each instruction to see how the operands will be used. In any case, the official documentation (_MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume I: Introduction to the MIPS32™
Architecture_) refers to `rt` as a _target_ register which can be either a source or a destination depending on the instruction.

Answer (score 2):

`lw` and `sw` share a common memory address computation, but differ in that `lw` reads from main memory and `sw` writes to main memory.  As a result, The `lw` and `sw` operations are necessarily opposites of a sort.

Reading from main memory into the processor means writing to a register (the value that was read), which is what `lw` does: it updates the register file without changing main memory, copying a value from main memory (at the computed address) into the processor.

While writing to main memory means reading from a register (the value to write), which is what `sw` does: it takes a value from the processor and writes it to update main memory with that value (at the computed address).

One problem is the use of the term "storing".  Most software people will use the term "storing" to refer to writes to main memory, however, as you'll note both instructions (`lw` & `sw`) "store", though one into register and the other to main memory.  Generally, when we can, we refer to `lw` as loading into a register to deconflict and avoid the term "storing" (though to some a value is "stored" into the register, and this is not necessarily wrong but not how we usually speak about register updates).

Comment: Thank you @Erik Eidt for the response. Since, I have to write the assembly code of a MIPS code, I am assuming that this is correct: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~zwang/files/cda3101/Fall2017/Lecture5_cda3101.pdf ?

Comment: Yes, you can see that on slide 21 (and as you quote) they use the term "assigned' to refer to updating a register's held value, and "stored" to refer to updating a memory location's held value. Further, hopefully it is clear that, loads read memory (while writing register) and stores write memory.(while reading register),  "Storing" is a traditional term, biased or oriented to what happens to main memory (rather than to the register, here `rt`). Main memory is (still) what holds most data structures, so this bias is reasonable yet today.

Comment: The bias of using store & write as well as load & read, all relative to main memory is also applicable for high level languages, e.g. reading data structures is, vs. writing/modifying them, since in high level languages, we are often speaking to our in-memory data structures (arrays, trees, databases, etc..) (more so than speaking to scalar & temporary variables and we don't even speak of the CPU registers),